# The present of FileOutputStream cause the InputStream.read error

Tags: java

I have some problem with Java IO, this code below is not working, the variable count return -1 directly.

```
public void putFile(String name, InputStream is) {      

    try {

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\TEMP\\" + name);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = is.read(buf);
        while( count >0) {
            output.write(buf, 0, count);
            count = is.read(buf);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

But if I commented the OutputStream such as

```
    public void putFile(String name, InputStream is) {      

    try {

        //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\TEMP\\" + name);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = is.read(buf);
        while( count >0) {
            //output.write(buf, 0, count);
            count = is.read(buf);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

The count will return the right value (>-1).
How is this possible ? Is it a bug ?

I'm using Jetty in Eclipse with Google plugins and Java 6.21 in Windows 7.
PS :I change the original code, but it doesn't affect the question

Comment: Is it the same file in InputStream and OutputStream?

Comment: No I'm trying to upload a file (InputStream)

Comment: It works for me. Are yo sure your File in Inputstream is present?

Comment: I'm sure about it here what I've done, I've put a buffer so I don't write directly into the outputstream and then using the buffer I write the outputstream and its works. It is a workaround. Now I'm trying to use some wrapper so the FileOutputStream is not write directly in this class.

Comment: Try to add `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch blocks. This can point you to the reason. It's also better to add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your post.

Comment: Yes after looking more deeply in the code I found that it is the same file InputStream and OutputStream. This is my error. I'm going to close the tread.